# Magento Move Category

Tags: category, category-tree

On an installation of Magento 1.9.0.1, I've noticed that moving categories programmatically doesn't change the `parent_id` column in `catalog_category_entity` and can leave things broken.

Let's say that category 5555 has the path `1/5/123/987/5555` and you do this:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(5555)->move(123, 333)->save();
```

The `path` column is correctly updated, as is the `catalog_category_product` table. However, the `parent_id` column in `catalog_category_entity` remains set to `987` and is not changed to `123`.

Simply changing the code to this fixes the problem:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(5555)->move(123, 333)->setParentId(123)->save();
```

Is this a bug in this version of Magento? It seems like the `move()` method should change the `parent_id` for me.

Comment: May be @benmark can help you more on this issue.